# How to reproject TMS with Mapproxy

Tags: tile-map-service, mapproxy

I has TMS in `EPSG:3857` and i want to reproject it in my local srs. My mapproxy config:

```
services:
  demo:
  tms:
    use_grid_names: true
    # origin for /tiles service
    origin: 'nw'
  kml:
      use_grid_names: true
  wmts:
  wms:
    srs: ['EPSG:3857','EPSG:100000']
    image_formats: ['image/png']
    md:
      title: MapProxy WMS Proxy
      abstract: This is a minimal MapProxy example.

layers:
  - name: ekb
    title: ekb
    sources: [ekb_cache_in]

caches:
  ekb_cache_in:
    grids: [webmercator]
    #disable_storage: true
    sources: [ekb_tms]
  ekb_cache:
    grids: [ekb_grid]
    meta_size: [4, 4]
    sources: [ekb_cache_in]

sources:
  ekb_tms:
    type: tile
    grid: webmercator
    transparent: true
    url: http://localhost:137/tiles/%(z)s/%(x)s/%(y)s.png
grids:
    webmercator:
        base: GLOBAL_WEBMERCATOR
    ekb_grid:
        origin: 'sw'
        tile_size: [256, 256]
        srs: 'EPSG:100000'
        bbox: [1490000, 360000, 1560000, 410000]
        #bbox_srs: 'EPSG:100000'
        res: [273.4375, 136.71875, 68.359375, 34.1796875, 17.08984375, 8.544921875, 4.2724609375,
        2.13623046875, 1.068115234375, 0.5340576171875, 0.26702880859375, 0.133514404296875, 0.0667572021484375, 0.0333786010742188, 0.0166893005371094
        , 0.0083446502685547, 0.0041723251342773, 0.0020861625671387]
        1:634 347

globals:
  srs:
    proj_data_dir: 'epsg\'
```

After i tried to get my reprojected layer in qgis by urls:

```
http://localhost:8082/tms/1.0.0/ekb/ekb_grid/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
http://localhost:8082/tiles/ekb/ekb_grid/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
```

i got 404 error.

I think that i have a wrong `res` block.
How can i generate it correctly? Or i have another mistake in config?

**update**
Error text:

```
[info] 192.168.80.85 - - [04/Apr/2018 13:45:13] "GET /tiles/ekb/ekb_grid/16/4380
3/45402.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
[info] 192.168.80.85 - - [04/Apr/2018 13:45:13] "GET /tiles/ekb/ekb_grid/16/4380
2/45402.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
[info] 192.168.80.85 - - [04/Apr/2018 13:45:13] "GET /tiles/ekb/ekb_grid/16/4380
4/45402.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Comment: Do you get any error after running serve-develop? After running mapproxy-util serve-develop with your yaml file you should see the error if there is any.

Comment: @senolozgur After mapproxy start i dont get any errors. But when i add my layer in qgis i got errors. I'd added error taxt in question.